# is realtime event listening for firebase_admin firestore possible?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using the python firebase admin sdk for my flask app. 
Is it possible to listen to realtime events on collections (like document addded)?

Some documentation indicates that it's possible, yet other documentation and my own testing indicates else wise.

#### Details

The documentation for [CollectionReference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/collection.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.collection.CollectionReference.on_snapshot) indicates that `on_snapshot` can be used to register event listeners on collections.

However, this [firestore tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) is saying that `"Note: Realtime listeners are not supported in Python and PHP."`.   So there are two contradictory sources
Furthermore, in my own tests I'm getting that `on_snapshot` is not an attribute of an `CollectionReference`, suggestion that this feature is not possible.

Can you confirm whether realtime listening in python firestore admin sdk is possible or not ?

#### Relevant Code:

The documentation for `on_snapshot` says this code should work

```
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client()
collection_ref = db.collection(u'users')
def on_snapshot(collection_snapshot):
    for doc in collection_snapshot.documents:
        print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
 collection_watch = collection_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)
```

However it's giving me an error 
`AttributeError: 'CollectionReference' object has no attribute 'on_snapshot'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't been released yet. The last release is from October 2018, and the `on_snapshot` method has been added in a November PR: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/6191

I think the API reference is auto-generated from the GitHub master branch, which is why it appears there.